# Vectorize cut off view of an image stack in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, vectorization, cell-array

I'm working with stacks of microscopy images. By stack I mean a couple of images acquired one on top of the other, as illustrated in this very home-made diagram: (sorry for the quality) where:

H = Image height in pixels

W = Image Width in pixels

Z = number of slices in the stack (i.e. # of images).

[image]

What I want to do is measure, for every 'height' position in the stack, an orthogonal "WZ view", i.e. a cut off view along a rectangle such as the red one on the image. Right now I have the following code which works well:

```
DummyProjMatrixYZ = zeros(SliceNumber,ImageWidth,ImageHeight,3,'uint16');

for h = ImageHeight:-1:1
    for z = 1:SliceNumber

        DummyProjMatrixWZ(z,:,h,:) = MovieCell{z}(h,:,:); % MovieCell is a cell array containing the individual frames (i.e. slices in the stack) of dimensions (Height,Width,3).
    end    
end
```

The code works fine, but I have to loop through the whole slices for every "height unit", which is not optimal at all.

**My question is:** How could the previous code be vectorized in order to gain speed since I will eventually work with quite large datasets. I guess I have a brain freeze and do not know how to do it efficiently.

Comment: 1) whats the size of MovieCell? , 2) why is it in a cell array and not a 4D matrix?

Comment: @natan 1) MovieCell is of size (1,z) where z is the # of slices, i.e. from 20 to 200 normally. 2) It's in a cell array because it was much simpler for previous manipulations I had to do with the images in it. But I agree that would make more sense to store the images in a 4D matrix.

Comment: if its just z is just 20-200 why not stay with the loop? how much time would you save?

Comment: well for small datasets it's quite fast, but I want to calculate HZ views as well in image sequences containing 20-50 time points (i.e. not only 1 as in my example)For a stack containing 20 images 1024x1024, it takes 1 second and for a 220 images-stacks it takes 9 seconds. Therefore I can expect that doing the calculation twice (for HZ views) for 20+ time points will take quite some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This basically looked like an `indexing problem` to me. See if this works out for you -

```
%// Get all of the data into SliceNumber*ImageWidth x ImageWidth x 3 numeric 
%// array. No more messing around with cell arrays is needed after this point.
A = vertcat(MovieCell{:});

%// Cocatenate data along dim3 to create a 2D array
A1 = reshape(permute(A,[1 3 2]),size(A,1)*size(A,3),[]);

%// Cut A1 after every ImageHeight rows to form a 3D array
A2 = permute(reshape(A1,ImageHeight,size(A1,1)/ImageHeight,[]),[1 3 2]);

%// Cut A2's dim3 into SliceNumber x 3 to create a 4D array
A3 = reshape(A2,ImageHeight,ImageWidth,SliceNumber,3);

%// Change the dimensions to match with original DummyProjMatrixWZ's
DummyProjMatrixWZ = permute(A3,[3 2 1 4]);
```

---

Shorter version -

```
%// Get all of the data into SliceNumber*ImageWidth x ImageWidth x Ch numeric 
%// array. No more messing around with cell arrays is needed after this point.
A = vertcat(MovieCell{:});

%// Cut A at every H rows and resize to H x W x Slice*Ch to form a 3D array
A2 = permute(reshape(permute(A,[1 3 2]),ImageHeight,[],ImageWidth),[1 3 2]);

%// Cut A2's dim3 into Slice x Ch to create a 4D array and rearrange dims
DPrjMatWZ = permute(reshape(A2,ImageHeight,ImageWidth,SliceNumber,[]),[3 2 1 4]);
```

Here, `Ch` denotes the number of channels used, which is `3` in the problem case and `DPrjMatWZ` is the final output.

Comment: Yep it works perfectly and the computation time for my 220 images stack was cut in half so the benefit for large datasets will be very important thanks that's awesome!

Comment: @Benoit_11 Very kool! Good to see the benefits really! :) You can try to merge final two lines into one and see if it improves any further.

Comment: Yep definitely. I must confess that I was hoping you would take a look at my question and propose some vectorization magic thanks!

Comment: @Benoit_11 Check out the just added Shorter version! Might be better with memory as less variables are used.

Comment: Nice! It works just as well thanks for the effort I appreciate it :)